# How can i move Angular dependencies from application to controllers?

Tags: angularjs

I am learning AngularJS and I have one application which use several separate controllers, and everything is splitted in separate files. Please note that there is no "$scope" because I am using the "controller as vm" syntax.

Application:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("myApplication", ['dependency1', 'dependency2'])
})();
```

Controller 1 (which would need only dependency1):

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("myApplication")
        .controller("firstController", firstController);

            function firstController($http) {
            ...
            }
```

Controller 2 (which would need only dependency2):

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("myApplication")
        .controller("secondController", secondController);

            function secondController($http) {
            ...
            }
```

Everything is working correctly, but this approach forces me to include All the dependencies files in ALL pages.

I would like to move the dependencies to the controllers:

New Application (without dependencies):

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("myApplication", [])
})();
```

The question is: what is the correct syntax for the controllers, in order to move "dependency1" to Controller 1 and "dependency2" to Controller 2?

Thanks!

Comment: you cannot do that.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ozLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad)

```
myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($ocLazyLoad) {
  $ocLazyLoad.load('testModule.js');
});
```

Read more over [here](https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs).